# How to pass API data to child components

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, api, rest

I am trying to create a very simple website called Currency Tracker. I am using the following API: http://api.nbp.pl/. I have managed to get the 'mid' and 'code' data with fetch method which I need to render the child components with. I'm still learning to use API. Unfortunatelly I'm stuck. I don't know how to use this data and how pass it down to render the components.

````
import MainPageItem from './MainPageItem.js'
import './MainPage.css';

fetch('http://api.nbp.pl/api/exchangerates/tables/A')
  .then(response => {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(data => {
    const mid = data[0].rates.map(currency => {
      return currency.mid
    });
    console.log(mid)
  })

fetch('http://api.nbp.pl/api/exchangerates/tables/A')
  .then(response => {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(data => {
    const code = data[0].rates.map(currency => {
      return currency.code
    });
    console.log(code)
  })
  
function MainPage(props) {
  return (
    <div className="main-page">
      <div className="main-page__currecy-list-container">
        <div className="main-page__currency-list">
          <MainPageItem currency="EUR" mid="4.5" />
          <MainPageItem currency="USD" mid="4" />
          <MainPageItem currency="GBP" mid="5" />
          <MainPageItem currency="CHF" mid="3.5" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}```

The MainPageItem is just a mockup. How can I pas the 'mid' and 'code' data to props render components?. Ideally I want to
````

Comment: Using `redux` to store the  api result at app state level and then share it across the app.
https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put the api calls inside your `MainPage` component, store the results inside some state (e.g. using `useState`) and then passing the data wherever you need, or just using it inside the component itself.

```
import MainPageItem from './MainPageItem.js'
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import './MainPage.css';
  
function MainPage(props) {
  const [codes, setCodes] = useState([])
  const [mids, setMids] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('http://api.nbp.pl/api/exchangerates/tables/A')
      .then(response => {
        return response.json();
      })
     .then(data => {
       const code = data[0].rates.map(currency => {
         return currency.code
       });
       setCodes(code)
     })
    fetch('http://api.nbp.pl/api/exchangerates/tables/A')
      .then(response => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(data => {
        const mid = data[0].rates.map(currency => {
          return currency.mid
        });
       setMids(mid)
      })
  }, [])
  return (
    <div className="main-page">
      <div className="main-page__currecy-list-container">
        <div className="main-page__currency-list">
         {codes.map((code, i) => <MainPageItem key={i} currency={code} mid={mids[i]} />)}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This is an example of what you can do in order to save the `codes` inside a piece of state of your component.

The `mids` part is very naive and I added it only to give you a hint on how to do that.

Comment: Your example doesn't show how `codes` is being shared with the other components.

Comment: @Andy I updated the answer in order to show a minimal example of how to pass the `code` to the child component.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Marco. It was very useful. Now I have a problem and I don't know how to assign mid values as well. I need to assign both codes and mids to the MainPageItem and now I'm not sure how to add mids additionally to child components after codes.map

Comment: @WorstProgrammerEver I added a piece of code in order to give you some hints on how to do that part.

Comment: @WorstProgrammerEver happy to helped you. If one of the answers solves your problem please consider to mark one of them as "accepted" in order to help other people to find the correct solution quickly.

Comment: Done it already! Sorry, it's the first question I ever posted here and I didn't know about that.

Answer (score 0):

useing props you can pass data to other component.

Comment: It's useless if you don't show any examples or provide any explanation.